# Accessing Canvas from Multiple Tasks

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas, task-parallel-library

I am trying to generate a map. I created a 2D boolean array which is representing accessible and not accessible part of the map. Now I am trying to draw some rectangles in canvas by multiple tasks. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

```
private void GenerateMapParallel(Canvas cMap)
{
    cMap.Children.Clear();

    var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Generate(0, 330, cMap));
    var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Generate(331, 660, cMap));

    Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
}

private void Generate(int start, int stop, Canvas cMap)
{

    for (int i = start; i < stop; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Map.instance.height; j++)
        {
            if (Map.instance.map[i, j] == false)
            {
                if(cMap.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                {
                   cMap.Children.Add(new Rectangle() { Width = 1, Height = 1, Margin = new Thickness(i, j, 0, 0), Fill = Brushes.Gray });
                }
                else
                {
                    cMap.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => { cMap.Children.Add(new Rectangle() { Width = 1, Height = 1, Margin = new Thickness(i, j, 0, 0), Fill = Brushes.Gray }); }));

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Application does not load like it is in infinite loop somewhere. Task1 is generating first top half and Task2 is generating the bottom half. Any ideas how to do it better way ? I am new in TPL.

Comment: Your for loop can be converted to a Parallel.ForEach loop

Comment: Which version of .Net are you using?

Comment: I know I can use parallel for each but I need to do it with Tasks.
.Net 4,5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are blocking the UI thread by calling `Task.Wait` on tasks in which you are invoking something on the UI thread with `Dispatcher.Invoke`. The tasks wait for the UI thread to be free and the UI thread waits for the tasks to complete. This results in a deadlock.

You should wait asynchronously with `await`:

```
private async Task GenerateMapParallel(Canvas cMap)
{
    cMap.Children.Clear();

    var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Generate(0, 330, cMap));
    var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Generate(331, 660, cMap));

    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
}
```

Another way to break the deadlock is to invoke the action asynchronously on the dispatcher instead of synchronously with [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: It works, but whole process takes way longer than non-parallel solution. I guess its do to Invoking ?

Also when I call the GenerateMapParallel(..) method I get the warning "The call is not awaited... and that I should use asynch" How do I do that ?"

Comment: @Safiron Very probable. You're not really parallelizing anything since the dispatcher uses a single thread and the rest is negligible.